# Page Token problems with Test Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having some trouble with generated **Test Users** with our app.

As described in the Access Token doc, I am requesting page token as follows:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/accounts?access_token=USER_TOKEN

which then successfully responds as follows:

```
    {
   "data": [
      {
         "access_token": PAGE_TOKEN,
         "category": "Hotel",
         "category_list": [
            {
               "id": "164243073639257",
               "name": "Hotel"
            }
         ],
         "name": "Hotel",
         "id": "890054954369219",
         "perms": [
            "ADMINISTER",
            "EDIT_PROFILE",
            "CREATE_CONTENT",
            "MODERATE_CONTENT",
            "CREATE_ADS",
            "BASIC_ADMIN"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "ODkwMDU0OTU0MzY5MjE5",
         "after": "ODkwMDU0OTU0MzY5MjE5"
      }
   }
}
```

However, taking the page token (PAGE_TOKEN from above) from the response and using it to do something page-related (for instance, viewing page's feed) results in the following OAuth error response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

So it seems as if the Test User's user access token works but not its page access token.

Note that there's no issue like this with actual Facebook accounts but it seems to only fail with generated Test Users.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is related to this [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/375350605994196/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who would encounter this issue in the future: This turned out to be a bug with Facebook... https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/375350605994196/